# Excel formula for calculation increase in amount

Tags: microsoft-excel

Please i need to know the formula in excel by which i can calculate the total cost for 5 years if
I have a number, and there is set increase in percentage every year. I need to total cost for 5 years. Using the increased number and percentage over it for 5 or 10 years.  I need to get the total cost.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: for example. I have an amount of 100, there is fixed annual increase of 10%, hence at the end of the year i have 100 + 10% = 110, Now for the next year i start with 110 and with the increase of 10 % at the end of the year i have 110 +10% = 110+11=121. The total for 2 years is 110+121=131. I need to be able to calculate this by excel formula for specific years say 5 or 10 so on.

Comment: Is this something like a loan repayment? Do you know the initial amount owed (much easier to work from), or the initial amount of one payment? You probably want CUMIPMT  but it depends what your exact question is. Edit and improve your question rather than replying in comments, please.

Comment: No. Actually more like recurring deposit, but annual single payment. I need the formula so any amount can be considered. It should not make any difference

Comment: for example. I have an amount of 100, there is fixed annual increase of 10%, hence at the end of the year i have 100 + 10% = 110, Now for the next year i start with 110 and with the increase of 10 % at the end of the year i have 110 +10% = 110+11=121. The total for 2 years is 110+121=231. I need to be able to calculate this by excel formula for specific years say 5 or 10 so on. – 
Saj. NOTE - I had made calculation error in my previous comment. I have corrected here.
 20 hours ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can do either of the following

```
Deposit 100
Rate    10%
Term    5
```

```
=Deposit*(1+Rate)^Term
```

or

```
=FV(Rate,Term,0,-Deposit)
```

***Edit***
To Match what you wrote in your **2nd comment, with the corrected math**, you could modify the `FV` formula to:

```
=FV(Rate,Term,-Deposit,0,1)
```

*(see line 3 in the screenshot)*

[image]

Comment: Sorry, it just gives the increase in amount by given percentage over the period.

Comment: @Saj if you just make a single deposit of $100 at the beginning of the term, it gives the correct answer. Are you making multiple deposits? If so, make that change in the FV function.

Comment: @saj see my edited answer

Comment: Thanks, this was what i needed.

Comment: @Saj Glad to help. Since my answer satisfies your problem, I would appreciate it if you could mark it as accepted. You can read [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more information.